# pyspark failed to read in csv file. WARN FileStreamSink: Assume no metadata directory. java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused;

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, hdfs

I'm trying to read csv file using pyspark. 
Before I installed Hadoop, I was able to read in the file using pyspark. However, after I changed my java version to java8 and installed Hadoop, I couldn't read in the file and an error poped out as following. I only changed java version and JAVA_HOME during installation. It seems that some settings have been changed. I'm new to pyspark and hadoop. I tried to see [connection refused](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HADOOP2/ConnectionRefused) but still have no idea. Could you please tell me where should I start to check?

Thank you very much in advance!

```
23/03/15 18:52:47 WARN FileStreamSink: Assume no metadata directory. Error while looking for metadata directory in the path: ../sales.csv.
java.net.ConnectException: Call From MacBook-Pro-890.local/127.0.0.1 to localhost:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
```

The below configurations are provided for your convenience.
FYI：
core-site.xml

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

hdfs-site.xml

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>1</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

zshrc

```
## JAVA env
export PATH="/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"
export JAVA_HOME="$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)"

## MAVEN env
export M2_HOME=/usr/local/apache-maven-3.9.0
export PATH=${PATH}:${M2_HOME}/bin

## Homebrew env
export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH
export PATH=/opt/homebrew/sbin:$PATH

export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON="jupyter"
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS="notebook"

export SPARK_HOME=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/apache-spark/3.3.2/libexec 
export PATH=$SPARK_HOME/bin:$PATH 

export SPARK_OPTS="--packages graphframes:graphframes:0.8.2-spark3.0-s_2.12"

## HADOOP env variables
export HADOOP_HOME="/opt/homebrew/Cellar/hadoop/3.3.4/libexec"
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_HOME/lib"
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=${JAVA_HOME}/lib/tools.jar
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying that HDFS is not running.

Make sure that `start-dfs` is successful, and when running `jps` you see both a Namenode and Datanode Process. If you don't see these, you need to look at the logs for those processes, not continue to try and run Spark code.

Also, as of Hadoop 3.3.4, you should be using Java 11, not 8.